# Validate services created before start a new one or rollback if someone fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-6.0

Currently, I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application with C#, and I have a `POST` controller method with multiple service calls; each service saves the info in the database with EF Core using

```
await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This is the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var addressModel = new Address
    {
        AddressLine1 = model.AddressLine1,
        AddressLine2 = model.AddressLine2,
        City = model.City,
        State = model.State,
        ZipCode = model.ZipCode,
        PhoneNumber = model.PhoneNumber,
        FaxNumber = model.FaxNumber,
    };

    var addressResult = await _addressesService.CreateAddressAsync(addressModel);

    var primaryContactModel = new Contact
    {
        FirstName = model.PrimaryContactFirstName,
        LastName = model.PrimaryContactLastName,
        EmailAddress = model.PrimaryContactEmailAddress,
        PhoneNumber = model.PrimaryContactPhoneNumber
    };

    var alternateContactModel = new Contact
    {
        FirstName = model.AlternateContactFirstName,
        LastName = model.AlternateContactLastName,
        EmailAddress = model.AlternateContactEmailAddress,
        PhoneNumber = model.AlternateContactPhoneNumber
    };

    var primaryContactResult = await _contactsService.CreateContactAsync(primaryContactModel);
    var alternateContactResult = await _contactsService.CreateContactAsync(
        alternateContactModel
    );

    var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();

    var advertiserModel = new Advertiser
    {
        Name = model.Name,
        AddressId = addressResult.AddressId,
        PrimaryContactId = primaryContactResult.ContactId,
        AlternateContactId = alternateContactResult.ContactId,
        IsActive = model.IsActive,
        CreatedById = user.Id
    };

    await _advertisersService.CreateAdvertiserAsync(advertiserModel);

    var message = "The Advertiser was successfully added!";
    TempData["SuccessMessage"] = message;

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

As you can see, I have three entities, `Advertiser`, `Contact` and `Address`.

One advertiser can have contact and one address, so the advertiser table has a foreign key to those tables; my question here is, how can I ensure the `Address` or `Contact` have been created successfully after the advertiser try to be executed?

And what happens if the advertiser fails? The contact and address have been already created, how can I rollback if the advertiser fails? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, You have three models in your project,
When creating these three models, If any one of these models fails to be created, the entire project will be rolled back, So I think you can use `EF Core Transactions`. Actually, The `SaveChanges()` method itself is a transaction, but if multiple `SaveChanges()` methods are submitted, `IDbContextTransaction` is required.You can try this code:

```
        IDbContextTransaction tran = null;
        try
        {
            tran = _myDbContext.Database.BeginTransaction();

             //.... create model.....
          
            tran.Commit();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            if(tran !=null)
            {
                tran.Rollback();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if(tran !=null)
            {
              tran.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

**Or**

```
using (DbContextTransaction transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            //.......

            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
            Console.WriteLine("Error occurred.");
        }
    }
```

You can learn more in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions);

Comment: You should check for `null` in the `finally` block, or better just switch to `using`.

Comment: @Guru Stron, Thank your for pointing that, I forget to include this code snippet in above sample code,.

Comment: But that transaction should be on the controller right? because there are my three database calls? so I should import the db context in the controller

Comment: Yes, you can inject dbcontext into controller.

Comment: Why not just `using( var tran = ...)`?